# Power BI , rest source , authentication and access (users)

Tags: rest, https, powerbi

I am fairly new to Power BI. I have two questions/clarifications:

Question 1:

I was wondering What type authentication is supported by Power BI datasets. I will explain with an example below:

Consider I have a Power BI dataset and some charts (a dashboard) in Power BI. The datasource is Rest WCF service on my premises. The users are my organizational users. The OData service is an HTTPS endpoint. I was wondering if authentication would work in that case? Would I be able to authenticate the user in this case. As my knowledge goes if the call to my rest service has a token in header, I would be able to call my STS and validate the user.

My question is when the dataset is refreshed, the call to my service (which is made from Power BI) does it also include a Token in the call header. I am assuming it would be because the user is already logged on to power BI using his/her organizational credentials. Can someone please confirm.

Question 2:

This question is again about user access/authentication. Consider that my organization has many users which have different level of access to data (some users would see more data/ some less based on user id). I develop some power BI datasets (models) and some dashboards. I as developer have access to all data, so essentially see all data. I then share them to end users.

The question is when any user uses the shared dashboards and refreshes the dataset, will his access (authentication) work and he sees only those data that he should ?

I am confused as to how this would work. Is it that when an user adds a shared dashboard into his profile, would he/she have his own copy of the dashboard/dataset or will it be an shared one. If it is a shared one then I guess the access thing would not work.

Please advise/suggest.

- Girija

Comment: it's best to post distinct questions on StackOverflow so they're easy to answer and discuss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question: if your data sources uses basic authentication it should work. You would build your Excel file or Power BI Desktop file to point to your data source, ensure it refreshes and then publish to the Power BI service.  If you're looking for OAuth, then that is not something you can do on your side yet.

Second question: depends on how you implement your solution.  If you're using the a REST API, the data is retrieved as the user who entered their credentials.  So if you share your report built on your data source, then the people you share with see your data.  However, if you use something like Analysis Service tabular as the data source, you can implement row level security in Analysis Service tabular, your users would instead login as themselves and see just the data they have permission to.